# Osk.exe not killed properly and continu working in background

Tags: 64-bit, kill-process, on-screen-keyboard

I am trying to kill instance of Osk.exe programmatically.

I have a dialogue that allow user to start osk with a button, and if they do not close it themself I close it via the code in closing form.

My code look like this for creation and closing.

```
    Public Sub ClavierCommandExecute()
        Dim path64 = "C:\Windows\winsxs\amd64_microsoft-windows-osk_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.19041.1_none_60ade0eff94c37fc\osk.exe"
        Dim path32 = "C:\windows\system32\osk.exe"
        Dim Path = If(Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem, path64, path32)
        Me.ProcessusClavier = Process.Start(Path)
    End Sub

    Public Sub FermerCommandExecute()
        Dim processOSK = Process.GetProcessesByName("osk")
        For Each proc In processOSK
            proc.Kill()
        Next
        Me.Close()
    End Sub
```

The thing is, if I do this that way, the osk process continue running background. I can tell it because when i lock my laptop, it open back the osk. If it can help i am still on windows 10 64-bit.

But if I close it manually with the close button or even through the task manager, everything work fine.

It would not be a problem normaly, but i feel it created a memory leak by not being killed properly.

Comment: Check what's the return value of `Process.GetProcessesByName("osk")`. Most likely the process name is wrong and your `for each` does nothing.

Comment: Thank Alejandro, actually the GetProcessesByName work fine. I get 1 process named osk and it goes in the loop. My belief is that there is another process attach to it called something else and i don't kill it. Or the 64-bit osk cannot be killed this way.

Comment: It could always be that the program launches yet another process from other file, or that you don't have permissions to kill it (it can happen if you elevated `osk`, you need to be elevated too to kill it, for example). 64 bits or not is irrelevant here.

Comment: Thank Alejandro for that answer. I would like to dig in that direction but i am not well educated in that subject. Could you point me out some ressource about that so i can try something on my side? Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the problem come from the fact that i needed to be administrator to kill properly OSK.exe.

I replace the simple processOSK.kill()
by that code wich allow me to kill it trough taskill as an administrator.

```
        Dim process As System.Diagnostics.Process = New System.Diagnostics.Process()
        Dim startInfo As System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo = New System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo()
        startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
        startInfo.FileName = "taskkill.exe"
        startInfo.Arguments = "/im osk.exe"
        startInfo.Verb = "runas"
        process.StartInfo = startInfo
        process.Start()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can close Onscreen Keyboard by using below code :

```
    public static void HideOnScreenKeyboard()
    {
        foreach (System.Diagnostics.Process process in System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("osk"))
        {
            process.Kill();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**